# Firebase Delete Function not working correctly

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, document

Some Strange thing is hapenning ..

I Am trying to delete document from firebase, the problem is 
even when the ID, isn't found on the collection
It gives me back , a successfull msg.

is it a bug on firebase ???

```
DeleteOrganization(id) {
    return this.afs.collection('organizations').doc(id).delete()
      .then( () => {
        console.log('Document successfully deleted!');
      }).catch( (error) => {
        console.error('Error removing document: ', error);
      });
  }
```

Comment: 1. Thank you for the answer.
I Think what you said is true, they just simply return true , if they can delete, or the document isn't on the collection.
But you know, sometimes, we need that :)

Thanks for the answer bro

Answer (score 2):

The delete method gives you confirmation that a document doesn't exist.  The document doesn't have to exist ahead of time.

If you need to ensure that a document exists before you delete it, you should check for that yourself, though I don't think you have anything to gain from that (it is just extra work for the same end result).

Comment: so, ur sayin it's not a bug?

Comment: @RonRoyston Realtime Database works the same way, so I'm going to say it's not a bug.